# How to type the result from locallstorage?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

There is this type:

```
export const enum AuctionsView {
  tiles = 'tiles',
  list = 'list'
}
```

State:

```
const [auctionsView, setAuctionsView] = useState>AuctionsView> 
       (localStorage.getItem('auctionsView') as AuctionsView ?? AuctionsView.tiles)
```

Set state:

```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('auctionsView', auctionsView)
  }, [auctionsView]);
```

How do I make a strict typing of what localStorage returns? Maybe there is some special generic for this? The current code allows you to return any string from localStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 'createTypeSafeLocalStorage' you can declare any fields you expect and make them type safe

```
function createTypeSafeLocalStorage<T extends object & Record<string, string>>() { 
  return new Proxy({} as T, { 
    get: (_, key) => window.localStorage.getItem(key as string),
    set: (_, key, value) => {
      window.localStorage.setItem(key as string, value)
      return true
    }
   })
}
```

Here is how to use it:

```
const enum AuctionsView {
  tiles = 'tiles',
  list = 'list'
}
const safeLocalStorage = createTypeSafeLocalStorage<{ auctionsView: AuctionsView }>()
safeLocalStorage.auctionsView = AuctionsView.list
console.log(safeLocalStorage.auctionsView) // 'list'
```

You could declare 'safeLocalStorage' somewhere globally

Update:

@thedude If you want to ensure values are valid, use:

```
function createTypeSafeLocalStorage<T extends object & Record<string, Record<string, string>>>(obj: T): { [K in keyof T]: T[K][keyof T[K]] } {
  const assertIsValid = (key: string, value: any) => { 
      if (!value || !Object.values(obj[key]).includes(value)) 
        throw new Error(`Invalid enum: ${value}. Expected: ${Object.values(obj[key])}`)
  }
  return new Proxy({} as any, { 
    get: (_, key: string) => {
      const value = window.localStorage.getItem(key as string)
      assertIsValid(key, value)
      return value
    },
    set: (_, key: string, value) => {
      assertIsValid(key, value)
      window.localStorage.setItem(key as string, value)
      return true
    }
   })
}
```

Here is how to use it:

```
const AuctionsView {
  tiles = 'tiles',
  list = 'list'
}
const safeLocalStorage = createTypeSafeLocalStorage({ auctionsView: AuctionsView })
safeLocalStorage.auctionsView = AuctionsView.list
console.log(safeLocalStorage.auctionsView) // 'list'
```

Comment: this solution provides no type safety

Answer (score 1):

You can use a type guard to validate what you get from `localStorage`

```
const isActionsView = (thing: unknown): thing is AuctionsView => {
   return (thing === AuctionsView.list) || (thing === AuctionsView.tiles)
}

const [auctionsView, setAuctionsView] = useState<AuctionsView>(() => {
    const item = localStorage.get('key')
    if (isActionsView(item)) {
        return item
    }
    return AuctionsView.tiles
})
```